# MYSQL. Extract data with column filtered

Tags: mysql

I got a table like this:

```
mysql> select * from users;
+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
| userid | username | password   | privilege |
+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
|      1 | user1    | password   |         1 |
|      2 | david    | goodboy    |         1 |
|      3 | admin    | mastermold |         5 |
|      4 | user4    | password4  |         1 |
|      5 | user5    | password5  |         2 |
|      6 | user6    | password6  |         1 |
|      7 | user7    | password7  |         1 |
+--------+----------+------------+-----------+
7 rows in set
```

Now, how to extract password of username who is called "david" by the only select query without "password" stored in it and result is in one field. (Don't accept "select * from users")?

Comment: Learn basic SQL? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select password from users where username='david';
```

Comment: it violates rule because it have a word "password" in the query

Comment: what do you mean by 'violates rule' here

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan select query doesnot contain password

Comment: then how about select * from users where username='david';

Comment: Yes.select query doesn't contain "password"

Comment: select * from user where username='david'; <== The result is in 4 field, not one field (rule)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you mean that your query result shouldn't have the string "password", if I have got it correctly. Even though I am posting the answer, You should really consider @MarcB comment and try learning SQL first.

Your query should go like this

```
select `password` from users where username='david' 
and lower(`password`) not like '%password%';
```

Comment: Rahul. You don't understand my mean. My mean: The query doesn't accept "password" string.

Comment: @jackvn, that's why I escaped password column, since `password` would be a reserve keyword. your escape it with backtique. Just run the provided query in my answer and see if it works or not.

Comment: @ Rahul. your query is stored "password" string. The rule does not accept it.

Comment: @jackvn, understood now. In that case the solution i see is, go bu the solution given by TinTran and using `columns ordinal position`, even though it's never suggested. Probably, you could have gone for `synonyms` but mysql have no support for that.

Comment: OK, i think so. I'm trying to find new way

Answer (score 0):

without using mentioning "password"?
well you could grab the column name into a variable and use that like this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d601f/8/3)

```
SET @columnName = (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM
                   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                   WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'users' 
                   AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 3);
SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT ",@columnName," FROM users WHERE username = 'david'");
prepare statement FROM @sql;
execute statement;
```

Comment: Tin Tran, One select query. Your solution is 4

Comment: Is this some sort of tricky homework where your professor is making you think instead of having a solution?

Comment: @TinTran, why to go for a dynamic query when you can escape the column name?

Comment: i don't know. That is a reason i need your help. Because i think it's impossible. But..maybe somebody have a good solution?

Comment: @Rahul because OP said can't contain "password", password isn't a reserved word by the way you don't need to escape it.

Comment: @jackvn, your question is bit confusing, do you mean that; no where in your query "password" string must appear (kind a organization security policy or so)?

Comment: you can create a view, or a function that alias the password column and then run your select on that. I don't see any other option.

Comment: @ Tin Tran, your solution like this: 
mysql> create view uesrs_temp (s1,s2,s3,s4) as (select * from users);
Query OK, 0 rows affected
mysql> select s3 from uesrs_temp where s2='david';
+---------+
| s3      |
+---------+
| goodboy |
+---------+
1 row in set


But this solution have 2 query.

Comment: well i can't think of any other way, it's probably impossible since mySql doesn't let you specify column by ordinal_position.

Comment: @ Tin Tran, I think so. another question: where are you from?

Comment: Victoria, British Columbia, Canada

Comment: @ Tin Tran, I'm from Vietnam. nice to meet you

Comment: I was originally from Vietnam too I came here when I was 11 yrs old

Comment: Can i got your skype ID?

Comment: sorry I don't use skype